# Execute Multiple Queries into single call onto Freebase

Tags: python-2.7, semantic-web, freebase, mql

I want to get the results of multiple queries into single call onto freebase,which is there in this chapter http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch04.html. I am using python for querying. I want to query like this

```
{                                       # Start the outer envelope
  "q1": {                               # Query envelope for query named q1
    "query":{First MQL query here}      # Query property of query envelope
  },                                    # End of first query envelope
  "q2": {                               # Start query envelope for query q2
    "query":[{Second MQL query here}]   # Query property of q2
  }                                     # End of second query envelope
}
```

and get answers like

```
{
  "q1": {
    "result":{First MQL result here},
    "code": "/api/status/ok"
  },
  "q2": {
    "result":[{Second MQL result here}],
    "code": "/api/status/ok"
  },
  "status": "200 OK",
  "code": "/api/status/ok",
  "transaction_id":[opaque string value]
}
```

As specified on that link. I also came across some of the question on SO, which are -

- [Freebase python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783772/freebase-python)
- [Multiple Queries in MQL on Freebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413875/multiple-queries-in-mql-on-freebase)

But they seems to be using the old API which is "api.freebase.com". The updated API is "www.googleapis.com/freebase"

I tried the following code, but its not working.

```
import json
import urllib

api_key = "freebase_api_key"
service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread'
query1 = [{'id': None, 'name': None, 'type': '/astronomy/planet'}]
query2 = [{'id': None, 'name': None, 'type': '/film/film'}]
envelope = {
    'q1':query1,
    'q2':query2

}

encoded = json.dumps(envelope)
params = urllib.urlencode({'query':encoded})
url = service_url + '?' + params
print url
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
print response
```

I am getting error as

```
{u'error': {u'code': 400, u'message': u'Type /type/object does not have property q1', u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global', u'message': u'Type /type/object does not have property q1', u'reason': u'invalid'}]}}
```

How can I embed multiple queries into a single MQL query

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the [Batch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch) capability of the Python client library for the Google APIs.